# With jQuery preventDefault() how can you do the default action?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
    if (answer){
        // do the default action
    } 
});
```

What code would I have to put in for the default action to be executed if the user confirms?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
    if (answer){
        // do the default action
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**or**

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure?")
    if (!answer){
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**or** even just

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    return confirm("Are you sure?");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just return confirm("Are you sure?"). That will return true or false, where false prevents the action.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.confirm').click(function(e) {
    return confirm("Are you sure?")
});
```